# Best PHP Search Framework to integrate into an existing Site

Tags: php, search, solr, lucene

I'm about to start working on an existing site's backend. The underlying database is huge and I am going to be working on the search functionality for the site. I am wondering if anyone knows of any good search frameworks that I could use to assist me in development.

The site itself, is not built with a framework, which makes things very difficult from a scaling point of view but I am working through that, I had considered Apache Lucene but saw that it is only included in Zend Framework.

I read about Apache SOLR but I'm wondering if this can be easily integrated into an existing system? And if it is worth the effort trying to do so?

Would I be better off writing my own search algorithms or can anyone suggest a suitable way of going about building this new search functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) is easy to integrate; they have a [PHP api](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-php).

There are some examples on the github page about how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

> *I had considered Apache Lucene but saw that it is only included in*
>   *Zend Framework.*

**Zend Search Lucene** doesn't require you to use the entire Zend Framework. You can selectively use just the components that your application actually needs. I have successfully used Zend_Search_Lucene component independently of the other components in the framework for a web site which has only static html pages and makes use PHP only for the search.

Answer (score 0):

@Javacadabra,**Apache SOLR** offers capabilities in an easy to use, fast search server with additional features like faceting, scalability and much more...

You can checkout [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/documentation.html)